# How can I output the query result?

Tags: python, django-models

I can save item but can not query.

```
items=PhoneItem.objects.all()
    for item in items:
        print(item)
```

the program throw error:

> in "for item in items:" throw exception:
>   **init**() takes 4 positional arguments but 11 were given

I have try to restart program but the problem still exist.

```
class PhoneItem(models.Model):

     name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     department = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     namePY = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     phoneNumberPY = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     departmentPY = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     namePinyin = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     phoneNumberPinyin = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     departmentPinyin = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     pass

    def toPY(self,text):
        pinyin=lazy_pinyin(text)
        res=''
        for py in pinyin:
            res=res+py[0]
            pass
        return res

    def toPinyin(self,text):
        pinyin = lazy_pinyin(text)
        res = ''
        for py in pinyin:
            res = res + py
            pass
        return res

    def __init__(self,name,phoneNumber,department):
        super(PhoneItem, self).__init__()
        self.name=name
        self.phoneNumber=phoneNumber
        self.department=department
        self.namePY=self.toPY(name)
        self.phoneNumberPY = self.toPY(phoneNumber)
        self.departmentPY = self.toPY(department)
        self.namePinyin = self.toPinyin(name)
        self.phoneNumberPinyin = self.toPinyin(phoneNumber)
        self.departmentPinyin = self.toPinyin(department)
        pass
    pass
```

I expect output all items result.

Comment: Instead of computing the redundant values at object creation time, consider using properties.

Answer (score 0):

You have rewritten init. But Django needs to get all fields in init and nothing else: 9 your fields, id and self. If you want to rewrite init you need to write all arguments. The simplest way is instead of rewriting init create factory method like that:

```
class PhoneItem(models.Model):

    @classmethod
    def new(cls,name, phoneNumber, department):
        return ...
```

Or you can do like so:

```
class PhoneItem(models.Model):

   def __init__(self, name, phoneNumber, department, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(name=name, department=department, **kwargs)
       # And everything you need is here
```